# How to calculate return value of invested amount

Tags: math

There is a small query related to mathematics.If anyone will help me to get this,i will be very thankfull.Suppose i invested 500 rs. per month for 2 year at the rate of 8% per annum.how can i return increased amount? And for help it's answer is 13053(returned value).can anyone help me to get this.

Please help me to get this.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about finance / accounting / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A yearly interest rate of 8% means a factor 1.08.

Since you invest an extra 500 every month, you first have to calculate the monthly interest rate from the annual interest rate:

> month_rate = year_rate exp (1/12) = 1.08 exp (1/12).

The amount you invest the first month will draw 24 months of interest in total, so that means:

> month_rate exp 24 = ( 1.08 exp (1/12) ) exp 24 = 1.08 exp (24/12)

After 24 months an amount of 500 will be worth 500 * (1.08 exp (24/12)).

The amount you invest the second month will draw only 23 months of interest, so after 23 months this 500 will be worth 500 * (1.08 exp (23/12)).

So:

- 1st month: 500 * (1.08 exp (24/12))
- 2nd month: 500 * (1.08 exp (23/12))
- 3rd month: 500 * (1.08 exp (22/12))
- 4th month: 500 * (1.08 exp (21/12))
- ...
- 24th month: 500 * (1.08 exp (1/12))

If you add all these amounts you should have your answer.